# Laplace Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, recursion

Show that ${\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\rbrace}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\frac{1}{s^n} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}$

**My Attempt:**

${\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\rbrace}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal e^{-st}t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}dt$

**Integration by parts gives:**

${\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\rbrace}=\frac{(2n-1)}{2s}{\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{3}{2}}\rbrace}$

${\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{3}{2}}\rbrace}=\frac{(2n-3)}{2s}{\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{5}{2}}\rbrace}$

${\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{5}{2}}\rbrace}=\frac{(2n-5)}{2s}{\mathcal L} {\lbrace t^{n-\frac{7}{2}}\rbrace}$

I start to see the $\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\frac{1}{s^n}$, but not the $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}$

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: When you have come down to the base case, make the substitution $u=\sqrt{st}$, and you will get the famous [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) (or at least half of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laplace Transform of $t^{n-1/2}$ is given by

$$\mathscr{L}\left(t^{n-1/2}\right)(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1/2}\,e^{-st}\,dt$$

Now, enforce the substitution $st\to t$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left(t^{n-1/2}\right)(s)&=\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{n+1/2}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1/2}\,e^{-t}\,dt\\\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{n+1/2}\Gamma(n+1/2)\tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $\Gamma(z)\equiv \int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\,e^{-t}\,dt$ is the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

The Gamma function satisfies the [Functional Relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition) $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma (z)$.  Applying this functional relationship repeatedly to the right-hand side of $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left(t^{n-1/2}\right)(s)&=\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{n+1/2}\left(\frac12\,\cdot \frac32\,\cdot\frac52\,\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2}\right)\Gamma(1/2)\\\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}
\end{align}$$

where we used $\Gamma(1/2)=\int_0^\infty t^{-1/2}e^{-t}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi}$.  Note that this integral can be evaluated by enforcing the substitution $t\to t^2$, which results in the well-know Gaussian integral.

Comment: What do you mean, by "enforce the substitution st->t"?

Comment: Enforce = Make.  So, if you prefer, let $st=z$.  Then, replace the dummy variable $z$ with the former dummy variable $t$.  This is effectively the meaning of the notation $st\to t$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Hehe, sorry about that.

Comment: No worry;  it was a good question.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the $\Gamma$ function,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathcal{L}\left(t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\right)&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-st}\,dt = \frac{1}{s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u^{n-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-u}\,du\\&=&\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\\&=&\ldots = \frac{(2n-1)!!\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2^n s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Jack; Just like mine ... ;-)) - Mark